# I am using for of loop in react, but this gives me an error "x is undefined". I can use the simple for loop, but using for of loop would be cleaner

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react and using this for of loop here gives me an error "x is undefined".

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function HomeContent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    let content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
    let contentList = [
      "Hi! I am Aaditya",
      "I'm a Freelance Web Designer currently based in New Delhi, India",
    ];
    for (x in contentList) {
      console.log(x);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="HomeContent">
      <div className="content"></div>
      <i className="fas fa-sort-down fa-5x next"></i>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: es6 modules run in strict-mode, so you need to define `x` in your for loop: `for(const x of contentList)` - also, don't use a `for...in` to iterate an array (see: [For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476))

Comment: You might be looking for `for(let x of contentList)` not `in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using a `for in`, and not a `for of`.
That said, you must declare `x`, so:

```
for (let x in contentList)
  console.log(x); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```js
for (x in contentList) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

To this:

```js
contentList.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```